# Example of a function?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functions

$f$ is a discontinuous and bounded function defined on a closed set $C$. 
Also there exists a non-discrete closed subset in the image of $f$ such that it's inverse is open.

Can you give an example of such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=2\chi_{(-\infty,0]\cup [3,\infty)}(x)+x\chi_{(0,1]}(x)+|x-2|\chi_{[1,3)}(x)$$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function, i.e., $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Note that $f$ is bounded and $[0,1]$ is closed and you have $f^{-1}([0,1])=(0,3)$ is open.

Comment: This is a correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}\chi_{(-\infty,0]}(x)+2\chi_{(0,1)}(x)+\left(3+\frac1{1+x^2}\chi_{[1,\infty)}(x)\right)$$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function, i.e., $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Note that $f$ is bounded and $\{2\}$ is closed and you have $f^{-1}(\{2\})=(0,1)$ is open.

Comment: I have edited the domain

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited the question since I want a non-discrete set as the closed subset.

Comment: See my new answer